# Problemas con dropone

Tags: jquery, dropzone

Tengo en un formulario dropzone el cual puedo subir varios tipo de documentos, aclaro que son archivo segun lo pedido en el formulario entre ellos estan:

**Documento de identificación
Documento de escritura
Factura**
Todos estos son 3 áreas de dropzone para subir uno o mas de cada uno de ellos.

El problema es que ahora necesitamos corregir en el siguiente código es que al darle eliminar a un archivo el input tipo hiden que se crea en el html se borren de acuerdo al id que se genero

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#file_identificación", {
    maxFilesize: 10,
    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
    dictRemoveFile: 'Eliminar Archivo',
    url: routedoc,
    headers: {
        'x-csrf-token': CSRF_TOKEN,
    },
    params: {
        avaluo: avaluo_ids
    },
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    success: function (file, response) {
        file_identificacion = response.file
        file_identificacion_id = response.id
        $(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('id', 'file');
        $(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('data-uuid', response.id);
        $(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('data-file', response.file);
        $('form').append('<div id="file_ide_' + response.id + '"><input type="hidden" name="file_identificación[]" value="' + response.file + '"></div>') //Se crea un elemento div con un id unico para ser eliminado.
        uploadedDocumentMap[file.name] = response
    },
    removedfile: function (file, response) {
        var uuid = $("#file").attr("data-uuid");
        var filePath = $("#file").attr("data-file");
        $("#file_ide_" + uuid).remove(); // Este es el input a eliminar
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: routedestroy,
            headers: {
                'x-csrf-token': CSRF_TOKEN,
            },
            data: {
                file: filePath,
            },
            sucess: function (data) {
                console.log('success: ' + data);

            }
        });
        var _ref;
        return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file
            .previewElement) : void 0;
    }
});
```

En el siguiente codigo: removedfile hay dentro hay un remove para eliminar el html guardado al subir la imagen pero este no lo hace solo elimina la imagen pero el input creado dentro del div no elimina

Comment: y de casualidad colocaste un console.log('pase por aqui');

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Si lo hice y me imprime el div#file_ide_e5ce907f-188a-4b39-9e2d-e095a67a2b04

Comment: me parece que si el id del div es diamico no va a poder ejecutar el evento... me parece...

Comment: @Francisco Núñez Pudiera asignarle una clase para ese div dinámico, para poder bindear el evento

Comment: @Francisco no es necesario solo tiene que trabajar con el nodo padre y hacerle un target al nodo hijo ...